# OpenCV solvePnP method works only of a small region

Tags: opencv, opencv-solvepnp

When I'm trying to recognize using solvePnP algorithm I'm receiving the data that helps to calculate sizes only near the bounds of the points I put into the solvePnP function.  The other sizes are incorrect. Why? Is the reason - wrong camera calibration?

That is, assuming array of points as `[A]` located at `[Blob]` (~15% of image) only points near the `[Blob]` has correct results the other are wrong. But if I do the same for the other array of points `[A1]` located at `[Blob1]` I'm getting the other results that work only near `[Blob1]`. If I use summ of array `[A2] = [A] + [A1]` I'm receiving totaly incorrect results. Why?

Comment: maybe (small) errors in your data? Typically, the further away you are from the data that was used to optimize the result, the bigger the error appears. Calibration and lens distortion might be additional problems or additionsl factors that increase the error.

Comment: @Micka , I found that measured rvec and tvec has got different values in different parts of images .

Comment: @Micka , am I right rvec and tvec must be the same in the whole image?

Comment: rvec and tvec are constant for a single object state with fixed camera pose. The object must be non-deformable. The camera must be pinhole camera.